# Get function details for diagnostics

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that takes a parameter - callback to be invoked. When the callback returns nothing I need to show a warning with as much detail about the callback as I can:

```
function testFunction(cb) {
   var result = cb();
   if(result === undefined) {
      // show everything I can about the callback function:
      // name, file name, line number, body / code
   }
}
```

How much of that information is it possible to extract from a callback parameter?

The only details I have been able to find so far are:

- `cb.name`, if it is a named function
- `cb.toString()` - to get the body / code

Is it possible in Node.js to get more from a function somehow, such as the source file and the line number?

Comment: You can't know because it is only variable, could be generate as return value from other function and not even have it's own line of code. If you have control of callback, you can trow error instead, put `result == cb()` in try block then capture stack trace, line of code, etc. from the caught error

Comment: @aarosil I know about the stack trace, but that only works if the callback throws an error. In my example it doesn't.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ptpoa4dw/

Comment: @cswl I don't know, I'm getting an error on `StackTrace` - is not defined. Is there an NPM package for that?

Comment: @vitaly-t it's a library..  https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js

Comment: @cswl nevermind, found it - `stacktrace-js`. But I only see the stack for the function that takes the `cb`, not for the `cb` itself. By the way, your fiddle demo does nothing when run ;)